# How to ask the network for the hardware specs from each computer using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking to create a spreadsheet of all of the hardware and all of the software in each computer on our network. I cant seem to figure out how to get the hardware or software information from each computer without going to each computer one by one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use WMI.

Look at:

http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html

and

http://www.activexperts.com/network-monitor/windowsmanagement/wmi/samples/

for examples. These are not written in Python, but it should help.